# How to upload doc,txt files using phonegap

Tags: cordova

I am developing a phonegap android application that wants to upload files(doc, txt, etc). Can anyone please help me to find a tutorial on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For uploading/downloading img,txt or doc files, simply use File Api(file transfer)**
For more detail use this link http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer

```
    var win = function (r){

    }

    var fail = function (error) {

    }

    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.fileName = fileURI.substr(fileURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    options.mimeType = "text/plain";
    var params = {};
    params.value1 = "test";
    params.value2 = "param";
    options.params = params;
    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(fileURI, encodeURI("http://some.server.com/upload.php"), win, fail, options);
```

Comment: file transfer plugin not working, showing warning 'Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-android version. cordova-android: 5.2.1, failed version requirement: >=6.3.0'

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the `File API` for Phonegap, specifically the `Transfer` method  you can view the [documentation here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File)

Raymond Camden has a [nice tutorial here](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/11/2/PhoneGap-file-upload-to-ColdFusion) that you could probably use for reference as well.